# Как разделить строку в sql на столбцы по разделителю

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имеется таблица:

| СТ 1 | СТ 2 |
| --- | --- |
| А | Z;Y;X;W |
| А;B | Z;Y;X |
| А;B;C | Z;Y |
| А;B;C;D | Z |

Необходимо разбить строки по разделителю ";" на отдельные столбцы, чтобы таблица приняла следующий вид:

| CТ 1.1 | CТ 1.2 | CТ 1.3 | CТ 1.4 | CТ 2.1 | CТ 2.2 | CТ 2.3 | CТ 2.4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | NULL | NULL | NULL | Z | Y | X | W |
| A | B | NULL | NULL | Z | Y | X | NULL |
| A | B | C | NULL | Z | Y | NULL | NULL |
| A | B | C | D | Z | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Количество столбцов, значения в которых нужно поделить по разделителю, заранее неизвестно. Так же нет информации про максимальное количество разделителей в строке (привел пример, когда таких встречается максимум 3, соответственно каждый из столбцов поделился на 4 столбца). Вероятно путь к решению данной задаче лежит через представление строк в виде массивов с помощью string_to_array:

```
SELECT string_to_array('А;B;C;D', ';') -> {A,B,C,D}
```

Однако, как указал ранее, количество таких столбцов заранее неизвестно.

Использую PostgreSQL 14.

Comment: Динамический SQL в руки, и вперёд.

Answer (score 1):

Пример

```
create table test (id int,ct1 varchar(100), ct2 varchar(100));
insert into test values
 (1,'А','Z;Y;X;W')
,(2,'А;B','Z;Y;X')
,(3,'А;B;C','Z;Y')
,(4,'А;B;C;D','Z')
;
select * from test;
```

Процедура разборки и сборки

```
create or replace procedure Pvtd() 
AS $$
declare sSql0 varchar(1000);
declare sSql1 varchar(1000);
declare sSql2 varchar(1000);
BEGIN
  -- упростим исходные данные: сделаем структуру линейной по одному элементу в строке  
  -- и запишем во временную таблицу vals
  -- содержание получившейся таблицы показано ниже в тексте
  sSql0:='create temporary table vals (id int,ct1 varchar(100),ct2 varchar(100)
        ,elem1 varchar(10), nr1 int,col varchar(10));';
  execute sSql0;
  with t as(
    select id,ct1,ct2,elem1,nr1,concat('ct1_',nr1) col
    from test t
    left join unnest(string_to_array(t.ct1, ';'))WITH ORDINALITY AS c1(elem1, nr1)
       on 1=1
    union all
    select id,ct1,ct2,elem2,nr2,concat('ct2_',nr2) col
    from test t
    left join unnest(string_to_array(t.ct2, ';'))WITH ORDINALITY AS c2(elem2, nr2)
      on 1=1
  )
  insert into vals
  select * from t;
  
   -- создадим временную таблицу - выходной результат
   -- здесь только динамический SQL
   -- список колонок таблицы создаем через string_agg
  sSql1:=concat('create temporary table pvtd_table '
      ,'(id int, ct1  varchar(100),ct2  varchar(100),'
      , (select string_agg(distinct concat(col,' varchar(10)')
   ,',' order by concat(col,' varchar(10)' )) from vals),')'
  );
  execute sSql1;

   -- собственно вычисление нужных данных с использованием CROSSTAB
   -- список выходных колонок результата также создаем через string_agg
  sSql2:=(select 
  concat('insert into pvtd_table select * '
    ,'from crosstab(',' ''select id,ct1,ct2,col,elem1 from vals order by 1,2,3'' '
               ,', ''select distinct col from vals order by 1'' ',')' 
    ,'as pvt(id int, ct1  varchar,ct2  varchar,'
   , (select string_agg(distinct concat(col,' varchar')
   ,',' order by concat(col,' varchar' )) from vals),')'
  ));
  execute sSql2;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- эта строка нужна, чтобы был доступен CROSSTAB
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;
-- вызываем процедуру, чтобы получить результат во временную таблицу
call pvtd();
select * from pvtd_table;
```

Вывод

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 4
```

| id | ct1 | ct2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | А | Z;Y;X;W |
| 2 | А;B | Z;Y;X |
| 3 | А;B;C | Z;Y |
| 4 | А;B;C;D | Z |

```
SELECT 4
CREATE PROCEDURE
CREATE EXTENSION
CALL
```

| id | ct1 | ct2 | ct1_1 | ct1_2 | ct1_3 | ct1_4 | ct2_1 | ct2_2 | ct2_3 | ct2_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | А | Z;Y;X;W | А | null | null | null | Z | Y | X | W |
| 2 | А;B | Z;Y;X | А | B | null | null | Z | Y | X | null |
| 3 | А;B;C | Z;Y | А | B | C | null | Z | Y | null | null |
| 4 | А;B;C;D | Z | А | B | C | D | Z | null | null | null |

Промежуточная таблица `vals`

| id | ct1 | ct2 | col | elem1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | А | Z;Y;X;W | ct1_1 | А |
| 1 | А | Z;Y;X;W | ct2_1 | Z |
| 1 | А | Z;Y;X;W | ct2_2 | Y |
| 1 | А | Z;Y;X;W | ct2_3 | X |
| 1 | А | Z;Y;X;W | ct2_4 | W |
| 2 | А;B | Z;Y;X | ct2_3 | X |
| 2 | А;B | Z;Y;X | ct1_2 | B |
| 2 | А;B | Z;Y;X | ct1_1 | А |
| 2 | А;B | Z;Y;X | ct2_2 | Y |
| 2 | А;B | Z;Y;X | ct2_1 | Z |
| 3 | А;B;C | Z;Y | ct1_2 | B |
| 3 | А;B;C | Z;Y | ct2_1 | Z |
| 3 | А;B;C | Z;Y | ct2_2 | Y |
| 3 | А;B;C | Z;Y | ct1_1 | А |
| 3 | А;B;C | Z;Y | ct1_3 | C |
| 4 | А;B;C;D | Z | ct1_3 | C |
| 4 | А;B;C;D | Z | ct1_2 | B |
| 4 | А;B;C;D | Z | ct1_1 | А |
| 4 | А;B;C;D | Z | ct2_1 | Z |
| 4 | А;B;C;D | Z | ct1_4 | D |

Comment: Большое спасибо!